# IE support for arbjor.js library

Tags: svg, javascript

I am evaluating the javascript library http://arborjs.org/ it works great on chrome, but not in IE. The reason I found out is IE don't support SVG, however even after installing
the javascript library "svgweb" which would add SVG support to IE, it didn't work.

any clues,

Thank u folks.

Karthik

Comment: Looks like canvas to me, not svg.

Answer (score 2):

IE9 does support SVG but there are a great many IE6+IE7+IE8 browsers around that do not.
However ie6-1e8 DOES support its own Vector language called VML

Start evaluating Raphael, when the Raphael js library detects IE6+IE7+IE8 it uses VML and when not it uses SVG.

http://raphaeljs.com

http://www.irunmywebsite.com

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Flash Canvas](http://flashcanvas.net/) for IE.  It doesn't support every Canvas event but certainly has decent support.

Here is a pretty cool [star field](http://flashcanvas.net/examples/www.chiptune.com/starfield/starfield.html)
and well [spaghetti lines](http://flashcanvas.net/examples/open.adaptedstudio.com/html5/many-lines/) demonstrating its functionality.

I really like [this one](http://flashcanvas.net/examples/www.andrew-hoyer.com/exp_src/cloth.html).